# Internal Server Error Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'id')

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I did run command in my console 'yarn hot' and command 'php artisan serve --port=8001' and got this error when I try to open the localhost. In console it writes about file, this code the code from this file
but I didn`t find here any mentions about 'id' property.`

```
<template>
  <div v-if="loaded">
    <MyFileManager v-if="isFileManager" />
    <router-view v-else/>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import {users, locales, labels} from "@/http";
  import {Component, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator';
  import MyFileManager from "@/components/views/MyFileManager.vue";
  @Component({
    components: {MyFileManager}
  })
  export default class App extends Vue{

    get loaded(): boolean
    {
      return Object.keys(this.preLoads).filter(key => {
        return this.preLoads[key] === true;
      }).length === Object.keys(this.preLoads).length;
    }

    preLoads = {
      currentLocale: false,
      translatableLabels: false
    };

    get isFileManager(): boolean {
      return  window.name === 'fileManager';
    }

    mounted() {
      this.$store.commit('setCurrentUser', this.$roleService.authUser);

      locales.currentLocale().then(({data: {availableLocales}}) => {
        this.$store.commit('set', ['currentLocale', localStorage.getItem('locale') ?? 'en']);
        this.$store.commit('set', ['availableLocales', availableLocales])
      }).finally(() => this.preLoads.currentLocale = true);

      labels.list().then(({data}) => {
        const translatableLabelsObject = data.reduce((carry, next) => {
          carry[next.translation_key] = next;
          return carry;
        }, {});
        this.$store.commit('set', ['translatableLabelsArray', data])
        this.$store.commit('set', ['translatableLabels', translatableLabelsObject])
      }).finally(() => this.preLoads.translatableLabels = true);

      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', users.updateLastSeenAt);

      this.$store.commit('set', ['settings', {
        logo: (document.getElementById('logo') as HTMLInputElement).value
      }]);

      const settingsData = this.$roleService.settings;
      const settingsObject = settingsData.reduce((carry, next) => {
        carry[next.identifier] = next.value;
        return carry;
      }, {});
      this.$store.commit('set', ['settings', settingsObject]);
      this.$store.commit('set', ['settingsArray', settingsData]);
    }
  }
</script>

<style lang="scss">

.vdatetime-popup__header {
  text-align: center;
}

   @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
     .sm-hidden {
       display: none;
     }
   }

</style>
```

I did restart the server and clear the cache but got the same error, and try to find where this 'id' is mention in that file but I didn`t find where it`s. This is the full error

```
[vite] Internal Server Error
Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'id')
    at createDescriptor (C:\Users\Bohdan\Desktop\nowa\headless-client-cms\node_modules\@vitejs\plugin-vue\dist\index.js:4010:17)
    at transformMain (C:\Users\Bohdan\Desktop\nowa\headless-client-cms\node_modules\@vitejs\plugin-vue\dist\index.js:4350:34)
    at TransformContext.transform (C:\Users\Bohdan\Desktop\nowa\headless-client-cms\node_modules\@vitejs\plugin-vue\dist\index.js:4739:16)
    at Object.transform (C:\Users\Bohdan\Desktop\nowa\headless-client-cms\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-6e2fe41e.js:39317:53)
    at async doTransform (C:\Users\Bohdan\Desktop\nowa\headless-client-cms\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-6e2fe41e.js:50043:29)
```

And this is the error I did got from the cmd console where I did run 'yarn hot'

```
[vite] Internal server error: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'id') 
Plugin: vite:vue 
File: C:/Users/Bohdan/Desktop/nowa/headless-client-cms/resources/js/components/App.vue
```

Comment: I did change the post, you can see the full error

Comment: no, It`s App.vue, console does mention about this file

Comment: [vite] Internal server error: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'id')
  Plugin: vite:vue
  File: C:/Users/Bohdan/Desktop/nowa/headless-client-cms/resources/js/components/App.vue this it`s mention about it

Comment: I didn`t change it, just did edit how is written corectly

Comment: What the vite setup I did need to do?

Comment: about App.vue I did got the error in the cmd console where I did run the command 'yarn hot'

Comment: I think this vue3

Comment: Yeah, I have it. What should I do with this file?

Comment: the first one is in the browser console, the second one is in cmd console